# To split a large file (For ex., 300GB) into smaller chunks of 100MB's in linux (centos 7)

Tags: linux, centos7, centos6

To split a large file (For ex., 300GB) into smaller chunks of 100MB's in linux (centos 7).

I have tried split command it does not work efficiently as I get an error "output file suffixes exhausted". Is there any GUI available for this? Hjsplit is not working.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu， there is a tool `split`, which split files into be parts.

e.g.

`split -b 100MB some-big-file-name.avi`

I think, on centos, there is a `split` command too. maybe try 
`yum search split` if not.

Thanks @Shawn

`-a, --suffix-length=N
              generate suffixes of length N (default 2)`

So, use `split -b 100MB -a 3 some-big-file-name.avi` if the generated parts outnumber of `99`

Comment: split command will only split till it reaches 99 number suffix after that i get an error "output file suffixes exhausted"

Comment: @ArpithaM have you tried using the `-a` option mentioned in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)?

Comment: Thanks..I understood how to use the option '-a'.